# Formview EditItemTemplate in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, webforms, formview

I have a product table that am updating. the fields updated are category_id, prod_name, prod_desc, prize, status. I am using a formview to do that updating. however i am having problems with the category_id. the category_id is a databound dropdownlist using a sqldatasource to fetch id and name from category table in the database. When a product has no category_id value, a null value is entered by default by sql. 
 The problem comes when i go to edititemtemplate mode in formview, the dropdownlist cannot show a null value from db so it throws an exception of:

> 'category_idDropdown' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it
>   does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

this is my code in the updateprod.aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="category_idDropdown" runat="server" 
                AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                DataSourceID="catnames" 
                DataTextField="category_name" 
                DataValueField="category_id" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("category_id") %>' >
    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Choose Category--" Value="0" Selected="True">
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

this is my sqldatasource code the dropdownlist is databound to:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="catnames" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cloud_Kewl.Properties.Settings.conString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [category_id], [category_name] FROM [category]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

& finally this is the sqldatasource used to update the product details:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="productUpdate" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cloud_Kewl.Properties.Settings.conString %>"             
        SelectCommand="SELECT prod_id, category_id, prod_name, prod_desc, prod_price, img_name, img_contenttype, prod_img, status FROM product WHERE (prod_id = @prod_id)"    
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE product SET category_id = @category_id, prod_name = @prod_name, prod_desc = @prod_desc, prod_price = @prod_price, status = @status WHERE (prod_id = @prod_id)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="prod_id" QueryStringField="prod_id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="category_id" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="prod_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="prod_desc" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="prod_price" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="prod_id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i looked up in the questions regarding the formview and edititemtemplate in this site, but none came close to give me any idea on how to approach this problem.
I tried to solve it programatically but not success in cracking this problem. Please help me, i looked for the solution for 3 weeks. no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Try rebinding your datasource prior to the null value being set:

```
protected void myFormView_OnItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList category_idDropdown = (DropDownList)(myFormView.FindControl("category_idDropDown"));
    category_idDropdown.DataBind();        
    category_idDropdown.Items.Add(0, new ListItem("Select", null));
}
```

The problem likely isn't that you're trying to select a value that doesn't exist, but rather that you're trying to bind a DropDownList that *already has* a null value to a datasource that doesn't contain that value.

Comment: My experience with this error  1)the bind value, the actual column name or parameter on the ddl doesn't match the parameter in the SQL query or the sqldatasource select parameter or the data types may not match.  2) mistakenly use the value from the sqldatasource that loads the ddl as the bind value saved and retreived from the database when selecting it. These can be different. The value saved in the database has to match one of the items in the ddl list. Handle for null or empty string in databound event before loading sqldatasource.